# .NET How to Send WebRequet to Specified IP address in same domain

Tags: asp.net, .net, httpwebrequest, webrequest

I have a problem. Whenever I'm sending WebRequest to https://myaddress.com, it resolves to the wrong IP address (this domain has several IP adresses). 
How can I specify IP address, which I want to send the WebRequest to?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way is you can edit the hosts file to avoid the DNS lookup:  http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/6-surprising-uses-for-the-windows-hosts-file/

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use the IP directly? Example:

```
http://123.345.567.789/

WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://123.345.567.789/");
```

Comment: Will work fine with http, may cause problems with https since the domain of the URL won't match the subject in the server certificate.